# Convert to hex and delete last two digits

Tags: c++

Hello lets say i number `1314173089` as decimal and `0x4E54B0A1` as hexadecimal.When i use printf, it converts correctly to hexadecimal by using `0x%X`. I would really want to convert somehow my number to hexadecimal and then remove for example last two digits from the hexadecimal number so it will be `0x4E54B0` as hex, but in decimal it shall be `5133488` and i want to have the decimal number stored in a int for another things - could someone give me a hand? So far i could only printf it but i dont know how would i do such a hex function myself..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply divide by `0x100`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const unsigned int a = 0x4E54B0A1;
    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << a / 0x100 << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `0x4e54b0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int hexFunction(const unsigned int a) {
    return a / 0x100;
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned int a = 0x4E54B0A1;
    unsigned int hex = hexFunction(a);
    std::cout << "Hex = 0x" << std::hex << hex;
    std::cout << "\tDec = " << std::dec << hex << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```